# TypeScript importing block.json - Wordpress Gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, typescript, wordpress-gutenberg

I am building a Gutenberg block which I have previously had working and am now refactoring to use Typescript. I am getting an error where it tries to import the `block.json` file and as a result the block does not get registered in the editor.

Here is my `tsconfig.js` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./build/",
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es5",
      "jsx": "react",
      "allowJs": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true
    },
    "include": [
      "src/*"
    ]
}
```

Here is the `block.json`:

```
{
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "bootstrap-components/accordion",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "title": "Accordion Block",
    "category": "widgets",
    "icon": "smiley",
    "description": "Example block written with ESNext standard and JSX support – build step required.",
    "supports": {
        "html": false
    },
    "textdomain": "bootstrap-components",
    "editorScript": "file:../../../build/index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:../../../build/index.css",
    "style": "file:../../../build/style-index.css"
}
```

which is imported into `index.tsx` using `import metadata from './block.json';`.

The error I get is:
`Argument of type '{ apiVersion: number; name: string; version: string; title: string; category: string; icon: string; description: string; supports: { html: boolean; }; textdomain: string; editorScript: string; editorStyle: string; style: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.ts(2345)`

Any help much appreciated.

Chris